# IBM Websphere 9.0 JMS authorization file not found

Tags: websphere

I want to see the content of the specific file - `integral-jms-authorizations.xml`

I don't know how it gets generated. Can someone please help me out here as this file is not present in my Websphere 9.0 installation anywhere?

Comment: Why do you need to see its contents? This file provides security configuration data for the integrated messaging system and there is no need to manually edit that. All changes should be done via admin console or wsadmin scripts.

Comment: I just need to check if there is something or not. But the main thing is that this file is not present in my system. What can I do to generate this?

Comment: This file will not be present if you dont have internal JMS Bus (SIB) configured, or if it security for SIB is not enabled. So if you dont have this file, you dont have any configuration for SIB security done in your system.

Comment: @Gas Thank you. Is there a documentation for that? I tried to create BUS and JMS Queue but even after that I'm not able to see "integral-jms-authorizations.xml" file.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I did a short research. That file was used in WAS v5.x. Starting with WAS 6.x the internal JMS server has been changed and that file is no longer used. You will not find it in any fresh WAS v9 installations. Currently authorizations for internal JMS resources are stored in the `profile/config/cells/cellname/buses/busname/sib-authorizations.xml`

You can find mentions of this file in the following links:

- http://ibmsystemsmag.com/ibmi/administrator/websphere/websphere-application-server-5-0-for-iseries-jms-s/
- ftp://ftp.software.ibm.com/software/dw/wes/pdf/jmstopologies.pdf

Comment: Thanks a lot. One last thing. Is there any reference to that sib-authorisations.xml file because i can't find it in the links you've given. I just need to show that to my colleague that integral-jms-authorizations.xml file is no longer valid.

Comment: @snakeman, the links I've put mention only that integral-jms-authorizations file as they apply to v5 and there was no SIB at that time. There is no reference to sib-authorisations.xml as all editing of that is now done via console/wsadmin, no manual editing required. If you change some SIB security settings via console and then do 'Review' before saving, you will see that this file is modified.